# Simulate a flashing text cursor in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting

What's a good way to insert a flashing cursor (e.g. a flashing thick underscore in DOS or vertical bar in Linux) in HTML?

This character/image would be trailing the H1 header and should look good at different sizes.

Comment: I just did it with `<script type="text/javascript">var i=0;window.setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("c").style.background=(i++&1)?"#00ff00":"#000000";},500);</script>
<style>
body {background-color: #000000;}
pre span {color: #ffffff;}` [...] `<span style="background:#00ff00" id="c">&nbsp;</span>`

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with just **CSS**, here is **vertical** bar [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/240/)

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: blink 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
```

Or you can use **JQuery** and  `setInterval`

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('span').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 600).animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 600)
}, 1200);
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 span {
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span></span></h1>
```

Comment: Why not just use a `pseudo-element` ?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do this using couple of code**
There's no library to do this. You can make a fake cursor using js.

**step 1**

Hide the main cursosr by,

```
caret-color: transparent;
```

**step 2**

create a span element

```
<input type="text"><span id="fake">_</span>
```

**step 3**

Make the span element blink using js

Answer (score 0):

What about just using the contenteditable property on the HTML element?

It will only work when the user clicks in the element but then it works "for free" without any JS or CSS etc.

Example:

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true">Edit me</h1>
```