# How to add a blinking cursors to a input tag

Tags: html, cursor, calculator, caret

I have a calculator and I wanna add a blinking cursors/caret or normal cursor/caret. how to do so?

Code:

```
<div class="first-row">
 <input type="text" name="result" id="result" placeholder="Enter and get result!" style="cursor:pointer"  readonly />
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulate a flashing text cursor in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118301/simulate-a-flashing-text-cursor-in-html)

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css.

just link the html to css.

codepen : https://codepen.io/ArtemGordinsky/pen/DgyQKy

made by : Artem Gordinsky

it has this keyframe:

```css
@keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```